# ELASTICSEARCH- Return filtered fields based on values

Tags: elasticsearch

I am developing a query in which I would like to identify those fields within "CES", those that show in the field "ces.des" or "ces.output" the value "jack"

```
 {"_source": ["ces.desc","ces.output"] ,
 "query": {
   "nested": {
     "path": "ces",
     "query": {
       "bool": {
          "should": [
            {"term": {"ces.desc": "jack"}},
            {"term": {"ces.output": "jack"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "nestedData": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "ces"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "data_desc": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "ces.desc": "jack"
                
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the output is :

```
            {
              "ces" : [
                {
                  "output" : "Laura", <-------------- WRONG 
                  "desc" : "fernando" <-------------- WRONG
                },
                {
                  "output" : "",
                  "desc" : "jack" <-------------- RIGHT
                }

               "output" : "jack",<-------------- RIGHT
                  "desc" : "Fer"
                },
             }
```

mapping:

```
{
  "names_1" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "created_at" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "data" : {
          "properties" : {
            "addresses" : {
              "properties" : {
                "asn" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "ces" : {
                  "type" : "nested",
                  "properties" : {
                    "banner" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "desc" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "output" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "source" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "tag" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "error" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "finished_at" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "total" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

I would like to filter only those that comply that present the values ​​according to the "bool" condition.
if (ces.desc == "jack") or (ces.output == "jack)"
return
ces.desc,ces.output key and value

Even if I add"agg", make a "JACK" count
doc_value = 2

What part of the query am I making the error?

query mapping:

```
{  
  "mappings": {
   "properties": {
      "data.addresses":{
        "type":"nested",
        "properties": {
          "data.addresses.ces": {
            "type": "nested"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your mapping to the following, i.e. **BOTH `addresses` AND `ces` need to be `nested`**:

```
{
  "aliases": {},
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "created_at": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "properties": {
          "addresses": {
            "type": "nested",            <------ MUST BE NESTED
            "properties": {
              "asn": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "ces": {
                "type": "nested",        <------ MUST BE NESTED
                "properties": {
                  "banner": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "desc": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "output": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "source": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "tag": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "error": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "finished_at": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you simply need to use [nested `inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#nested-inner-hits):

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data.addresses.ces",
      "inner_hits": {},               <---- ADD THIS
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "data.addresses.ces.desc": "jack"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "data.addresses.ces.output": "jack"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "nestedData": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "data.addresses.ces"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "data_desc": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "data.addresses.ces.desc": "jack"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the response will only contain the nested inner hits containing `jack`

Comment: Return a error:
"Cannot execute inner hits. One or more parent object fields of nested field [ces] are not nested. All parent fields need to be nested fields too

Comment: Can you show your index mapping and a sample document please?

Comment: In the statement I wanted to summarize it so as not to attach too large a json, but I have edited the statement to add the mapping

Comment: Ok, then you need to replace `ces` by `data.addresses.ces` in the query, unless `data.addresses` is really an array, in which case it won't work because it is not nested

Comment: data.addresses is a array.
I configured the data.addresses.ces field because I was unable to access the values ​​of data.addresses.ces.desc and data.addresses.ces.output
Should I change the mapping settings?
Thank you for your answers

Comment: Have you tried the query with `data.addresses.ces` instead of `ces` ? what does it yield?

Comment: yes, in the statement I only put "ces" to make it more summarized

Comment: I meant the query in my answer, have you tried it with `data.addresses.ces`?

Comment: Yes, and the error is the same
 "Cannot execute inner hits. One or more parent object fields of nested field [data.addresses.ces] are not nested. All parent fields need to be nested fields too"
The mapping is the same.
Adresses and Ces fields are arrays. I don't know if this information can help

Comment: Then you need to configure `addresses` to be nested as well and then reindex all your data

Comment: The assignment of nested fields in adresses and then in serv does not work, I have opened another query in case you could help me to solve the complexity of the json with many arrays within other arrays

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137877/elasticsearch-nested-object-under-path-data-addresses-ces-is-not-of-nested-typ

Thank you

Comment: This question has opened other issue.
I dont be able to assign adressess and ces to nested field.
I think when I can change those fields as nested as you have told me, I will be able to use inner_hits and get the filter.
I have opened this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137877/elasticsearch-nested-object-under-path-data-addresses-ces-is-not-of-nested-typ

Comment: But in your other question `ces` is not nested anymore ??? why???

Comment: And why opening another question, while we could have solved the problem in this one?

Comment: when I assign the field adresses and ces, according to the mapping they come out as nested fields, but when I execute the query with inner_hits, it returns the error:

"cannot execute inner hits. one or more parent object fields of nested field [data.addresses.ces] are not nested. all parent fields need to be nested fields too"

Comment: yeah, we know that, that's why I asked you to make BOTH `addresses` nested and `ces` nested and try again, but in your new question you didn't

Comment: I made the mapping in adresses field as ces in the way I have written above
and still inner_hits doesn't work

Comment: It seems we don't understand each other. So I've updated my answer with all the required steps, please check again. I closed the other question by the way, because it's a duplicate of this one

Comment: After multiples changes in the mapping, your solution was very usefull.
The problem that I had not seen was the "data" field is nested field too.
I had to change the type in 3 fields to nested (ces, addreses and data)
Thank you so much for your patience and tips.