# Search matching object inside document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, full-text-search

I have a documents with many nested fields and array of objects inside them.
So when I perform search, how can I get only the matching object inside the array of object, not the entire document?

```
{
  "name": "Olivia",
  "jobs": [
    {
      "title": "Accountant",
      "offices": [
        {
          "city": "Paris",
          "address": "Her adress"
        },
        {
          "city": "NYC",
          "address": "New adress"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Judge",
      "offices": [
        {
          "city": "Paris",
          "address": "Judge adress"
        },
        {
          "city": "NYC",
          "address": "New judge adress"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Jobs and offices are nested
What I want to have in my search are: her name, jobs and offices where the city is "Paris", in normal search I get both of the offices where city are Paris and NYC

Is there a way to get only the offices having "Paris" as city?

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63133940/4604579 (hint: use nested inner_hits)

Comment: Thank you it is useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [nested inner_hits along with _source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits-source), to get only the offices having "Paris" as city

Adding a working example with index data (same as that given in ques), mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "jobs": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "offices": {
            "type": "nested"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "jobs.offices",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "jobs.offices.city": "Paris"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "_source": [
          "jobs.offices.address"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "inner_hits": {
          "jobs.offices": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 0.6931471,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "67074755",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "jobs",
                    "offset": 0,
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "offices",
                      "offset": 0
                    }
                  },
                  "_score": 0.6931471,
                  "_source": {
                    "address": "Her adress"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "67074755",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "jobs",
                    "offset": 1,
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "offices",
                      "offset": 0
                    }
                  },
                  "_score": 0.6931471,
                  "_source": {
                    "address": "Judge adress"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```